# Second derivative test for minimization on the surface $xyz=C$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier

Let $p,q,r$ be fixed positive constants.

Edited to include the constraint:

The constraint is $g(x,y,z)=xyz=C$, where $C$ is positive.

I am trying to show that the one critical point that I found, for the function

$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^p}{p}+\frac{y^q}{q}+\frac{z^r}{r}$$

is a minimizer, so I think I would want to show that the Hessian matrix of $f$, evaluated at the critical point, is positive-definite.

The Hessian was computed easily enough -- it's diagonal, so the eigenvalues of the matrix can be just be read off.

However, the diagonal elements are of the form $(p-1)C^A$, ... , $(r-1)C^D$,

where $C$ is positive.

Although we know that $p,q,r$ are positive numbers by assumption, we don't know whether any of $(p-1)$, $(q-1)$, or $(r-1)$ are positive or negative.

So, I can't say for sure that the matrix has positive eigenvalues.

Should I instead use another approach to convince myself that this one critical point found must be a minimizer?

Comment: If it is a constrianed optimization problem then you have to use Lagrange multilier, it is not enough to find the Hesian of  $f$.

Comment: Hi, @Nizar, in fact the lagrange multiplier method led me to the critical point -- there was only one critical point along the level set g=xyz=c.  Now, I don't know whether this point is a minimizer -- although it must be, since the question is asking to minimize f subject to xyz=c.  I just would like to better justify why this point is a minimizer, so I think the Hessian matrix does play a role here, *after* having used Lagrange multipliers.  What do you think?  Thanks

Comment: Because I think that checking whether the critical point is a minimizer, by checking the Hessian matrix, is irrespective of *how* we got the critical point in the first place -- which was by the method of Lagrange multipliers.  Please feel free to comment @Nizar.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When exponents get in the way, logarithms come to the rescue. Introduce new variables $u=\log x$, $v=\log y$, $w=\log z$. The problem changes to minimizing 
$$f(u,v,w)=\frac{1}{p}e^{pu}+\frac{1}{q}e^{qv}+\frac{1}{r}e^{rw}$$
subject to the **linear** constraint $u+v+w=\log C$.

The linearity of constraint is important, because it simplifies the second derivative test for constrained extremum. With a linear constraint, we just restrict attention  to a subspace when testing the positive/negative definiteness of the Hessian. With a nonlinear constraint we enter the world of [bordered Hessians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Bordered_Hessian) — the ordinary Hessian no longer suffices, because the curvature of the surface to which the function is constrained can affect the nature of extremum.

In the above case, $f$ is obviously convex (sum of convex functions), so its restriction to a hyperplane is convex, too.